# Why do you need fitness scaling in Genetic Algorithms?

Tags: genetic-algorithm

Reading the book "Genetic Algorithms" by David E. Goldberg, he mentions fitness scaling in Genetic Algorithms.

My understanding of this function is to constrain the strongest candidates so that they don't flood the pool for reproduction.

Why would you want to constrain the best candidates? In my mind having as many of the best candidates as early as possible would help get to the optimal solution as fast as possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What if your early best candidates later on turn out to be evolutionary dead ends? Say, your early fittest candidates are big, strong agents that dominate smaller, weaker candidates. If all the weaker ones are eliminated, you're stuck with large beasts that maybe have a weakness to an aspect of the environment that hasn't been encountered yet that the weak ones can handle: think dinosaurs vs tiny mammals after an asteroid impact. Or, in a more deterministic setting that is more likely the case in a GA, the weaker candidates may be one or a small amount of evolutionary steps away from exploring a whole new fruitful part of the fitness landscape: imagine the weak small critters evolving flight, opening up a whole new world of possibilities that the big beasts most likely will never touch.

The underlying problem is that your early strongest candidates may actually be in or around a *local maximum* in fitness space, that may be difficult to come out of. It could be that the weaker candidates are actually closer to the *global* maximum.

In any case, by pruning your population aggressively, you reduce the *genetic diversity* of your population, which in general reduces the search space you are covering and limits how fast you can search this space. For instance, maybe your best candidates *are* relatively close to the global best solution, but just inbreeding that group may not move it much closer to it, and you may have to wait for enough random positive mutations to happen. However, perhaps one of the weak candidates that you wanted to cut out has some gene that on its own doesn't help much, but when crossed with the genes from your strong candidates in may cause a big evolutionary jump! Imagine, say, a human crossed with spider DNA.

Comment: That totally makes sense! Thanks P.s. The terms `local maximum` and `global maximum` are they a common term? Or something you coined?

Comment: They are very common yeah, though often you may also see local/global _minimum_, when it's more intuitive to think in terms of minimizing a cost function rather than maximizing a fitness function. See for instance https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxima_and_minima.

Answer (score 7):

@sgvd's answer makes valid points but I would like to elaborate more.

First of all, we need to define what fitness scaling actually means. If it means just multiplying the fitnesses by some factor then this does **not** change the relationships in the population - if the best individual had 10 times higher fitness than the worst one, after such multiplication this is still true (unless you multiply by zero which makes no real sense). So, a much more sensible fitness scaling is an affine transformation of the fitness values:

```
scaled(f) = a * f + b
```

i.e. the values are multiplied by some number **and** offset by another number, up or down.

Fitness scaling makes sense only with certain types of selection strategies, namely those where the selection probability is proportional to the fitness of the individuals<sup>1</sup>.

Fitness scaling plays, in fact, **two** roles. The first one is merely practical - if you want a probability to be proportional to the fitness, you need the fitness to be positive. So, if your raw fitness value can be negative (but is limited from below), you can adjust it so you can compute probabilities out of it. *Example: if your fitness gives values from the range [-10, 10], you can just add 10 to the values to get all positive values.*

The second role is, as you and @sgvd already mentioned, to limit the capability of the strongest solutions to overwhelm the weaker ones. The best illustration would be with an example.

Suppose that your raw fitness values gives values from the range [0, 100]. If you left it this way, the worst individuals would have zero probability of being selected, and the best ones would have up to 100x higher probability than the worst ones (excluding the really worst ones). However, let's set the scaling factors to `a = 1/2, b = 50`. Then, the range is transformed to [50, 100]. And right away, two things happen:

1. Even the worst individuals have non-zero probability of being selected.
2. The best individuals are now only 2x more likely to be selected than the worst ones.

## Exploration vs. exploitation

By setting the scaling factors you can control whether the algorithm will do more exploration over exploitation and vice versa. The more "compressed"<sup>2</sup> the values are going to be after the scaling, the more exploration is going to be done (because the likelihood of the best individuals being selected compared to the worst ones will be decreased). And vice versa, the more "expanded"<sup>2</sup> are the values going to be, the more exploitation is going to be done (because the likelihood of the best individuals being selected compared to the worst ones will be increased).

## Other selection strategies

As I have already written at the beginning, fitness scaling only makes sense with selection strategies which derive the selection probability proportionally from the fitness values. There are, however, other selection strategies that do not work like this.

**Ranking selection**

Ranking selection is identical to roulette wheel selection but the numbers the probabilities are derived from are not the raw fitness values. Instead, the whole population is sorted by the raw fitness values and the rank (i.e. the position in the sorted list) is the number you derive the selection probability from.

This totally erases the discrepancy when there is one or two "big" individuals and a lot of "small" ones. They will just be ranked.

**Tournament selection**

In this type of selection you don't even need to know the absolute fitness values at all, you just need to be able to compare two of them and tell which one is better. To select one individual using tournament selection, you randomly pick a number of individuals from the population (this number is a parameter) and you pick the best one of them. You repeat that as long as you have selected enough individuals.

Here you can also control the exploration vs. exploitation thing by the size of the tournament - the larger the tournament is the higher is the chance that the best individuals will take part in the tournaments.

---

<sup>1</sup> An example of such selection strategy is the classical roulette wheel selection. In this selection strategy, each individual has its own section of the roulette wheel which is proportional in size to the particular individual's fitness.

<sup>2</sup> Assuming the raw values are positive, the scaled values get compressed as `a` goes down to zero and as `b` goes up. Expansion goes the other way around.